# Como animar un icono al pasar el mouse sobre un div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir quiero al pasar el mouse sobre cada caja de color que es un div, se mueva solamente un poco el logo hacia arriba

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad `transform: translateY()` en css

```
div .icon {
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

div:hover .icon {
    transform: rotateY(-10px);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso deberia usar el selector :hover desde su css.

puede intentar algo como esto:

```css
#icono{
  transition: transform .2s ease-in;
}
.container{
  background: cyan; 
  padding: 15px;
  width: 20px;
}
.container:hover #icono{
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<svg id="icono" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-alarm" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8.5 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.362l-1.429 2.38a.5.5 0 1 0 .858.515l1.5-2.5A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5.5z"/>
  <path d="M6.5 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1H7v1.07a7.001 7.001 0 0 0-3.273 12.474l-.602.602a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.708l.746-.746A6.97 6.97 0 0 0 8 16a6.97 6.97 0 0 0 3.422-.892l.746.746a.5.5 0 0 0 .707-.708l-.601-.602A7.001 7.001 0 0 0 9 2.07V1h.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3zm1.038 3.018a6.093 6.093 0 0 1 .924 0 6 6 0 1 1-.924 0zM0 3.5c0 .753.333 1.429.86 1.887A8.035 8.035 0 0 1 4.387 1.86 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 3.5zM13.5 1c-.753 0-1.429.333-1.887.86a8.035 8.035 0 0 1 3.527 3.527A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 1z"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Lo intentare, muchas gracias